# Is there a bash/terminal command that will clear content prior to the last command?

Tags: command-line, bash

Use case: I'm working in bash/terminal and have been typing several commands and I've just run something and it's spewed some output. I'm trying to find where that output started and have to visually search the page to see where the command is that I typed.

Now had I anticipated that I was going to struggle to find the start of the content I would have run `clear && <my command>`.

So what I'm looking for is something like `clear -1` which would (1) grab all the content since the last command, (2) run `clear`, and then (3) paste the content into the terminal.

Comment: Have you considered using `<my command> | less` ?

Comment: That would work but replies on anticipating that I would need it. `clear && <my command>` works (or quicker `CTRL` + `L` as @SabinReneFigaro pointed out) just as well but again requires that you know ahead of time.

I'm looking for something that will work after the fact.

Comment: `bash`'s precognition is worse then yours...  Any solution that I can think of that adds precognition to `bash` would be ugly.  e.g. you could spawn a new terminal for each and every command you type and then have to close it after the command finishes...

Comment: @Fabby I don't think so. If bash stored the results of the last command in a buffer then it could easily (1) clear and (2) paste.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned piping the command to | less, will make it clear.

If you are using bash you can also press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>L</kbd> to clear, then run the command. This is what i do :)

Comment: Thanks - both of those work but rely on precognition that you need them and can't be used after the fact.